# Any way to disable the Accessibility Checker on a Workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, office365, microsoft-excel-365

I am working on a project that for security reasons needs to have the accessibility checker disabled. Although through settings I can disable it on my excel, I need to find a way either through VBA or through normal sheet settings to disable this feature on the workbook itself, so that other users don't have access to the issues pulled from Accessibility Inspection Results.

Any ideas or solutions would be greatly appreciated.